# Meaning of "He may not come today"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, modal-verbs, phrase-choice

I suppose that

> He may not come today

means that he is not allowed to come today. Right? But what is the right way to say that he is allowed not to come today?

> He may not to come today

Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the meaning of "He may not come today" is ambiguous, at least when written.  You would have to use context to understand what is meant.

When spoken, there would normally be a different intonation, depending on what the speaker intends to say.  If there is no particular emphasis, or if the emphasis is slightly on "may" the meaning is, "The *possibility* that he will come is small."

If instead there is a heavy emphasis on either "may not" or just "not" then the meaning is, "He is not *allowed* to come today."  When stating these kind of imperatives this kind of emphasis is common.  For example:

> No, you may **not** have another cookie.
>
> They may **not** come into the house until they've taken off their muddy boots.

If you want to emphasize the first meaning, you can say something like:

> He **may or may not** come today.

This makes it clear that you are talking about *possibility* rather than *permission*.

In any case, "He may not *to* come today," is not grammatical.